# Python2.7 read csv file and read from the next line

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I read the csv file. And then I passed empty row.
When I find a line that is not empty, do not read it and read from the next line.
How can I do this?
This is my code.

```
f = open(self.row, 'r') #file open
for line in f.xrealines():
    if not line.strip() : #check if a line is empty or not
       continue
    else:
       #I want to skip one line and then adjust next line.
       row = line.strip('Wn').split(".')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open(self.row, 'r') #file open
for line in f.xreadlines():
    if not line.strip() : #check if a line is empty or not
       continue
    else:
       #I want to skip one line and then adjust next line.
       row = line.strip('Wn').split(".")
```

check now!!!
you seem to have typos